# Whats the difference between finish() and finishActivity(int requestCode) in android

Tags: android

Can anyone explain me the difference between `finish()` and `finishActivity(int requestCode)`. And the situation of where to use them aptly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

`finish()` Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult().

`finishActivity(int requestCode)` is used to finish another activity that you had previously started with startActivityForResult(Intent, int)

Comment: I believe this answer may be somewhat outdated. I ran into a problem using `finishActivity(int)` to return to an activity started with `startActivityForResult(int)`, and found it did not work *at all*. It took a rebuild, a reset, and finally implementing `finish()` ***instead*** before it actually worked.

Answer (score 15):

Read Following:

**public void finish ()**

> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The
>   ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via
>   onActivityResult().

**public void finishActivity (int requestCode)**

> Force finish another activity that you had previously started with
>   **startActivityForResult(Intent, int)**.

For further reading have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29).

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but you can make it better by including a summary or relevant portions of the pages you're linking to. This will also help your answer remain great even if the links you included break in the future. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer

Comment: I have quoted required lines before your comments. You are taking time to refresh the page.

Answer (score 3):

`finish()` Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The `ActivityResult` is propagated back to whoever launched you via `onActivityResult()`.

`finishActivity(int requestCode)` Force finish another activity that you had previously started with `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`.

`requestCode` The request code of the activity that you had given to `startActivityForResult()`. If there are multiple activities started with this request code, they will all be finished.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you can call other Activities in Android from another Activity via an Intent in Android. When you call [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), you're calling another Activity in hopes that a result of code/change in the state of your app will happen. For example, I run my Main Activity, however I call another Activity that sets various fields/variables in the app to certain values (i.e. a user setting up the app's settings). Then, when that Activity has finished and you must return to the Activity that invoked it, you may call finishActivity to send a requestCode that will flag whether the Activity invoked has performed in a way that you desired.