# Android: return to the previous Activity error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have and Menu Manager apps.
The first `MainActivity` will call the `MenuActivity`
The `MenuActivity` will call the `Add_New_DishActivity`
The problem is, when in Menu I can return to Main by using System.exit(1) and finish()
However when I try to return from Add_New_Dish to Menu, there is an error  System.exit(1) and finish()
I have tried to use finishActivity(1); and only finish() in Add_New_Dish, but it doesn't work.
Please take a look at my code:

In Main, I used this codes to call the Menu

```
...
Intent intent = new Intent(context,Menu.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
...
```

in Menu, I used this codes to return to Main

```
  public void homButton_OnClick()
    {
        System.exit(1);
        finish();
    }
```

in Menu, I used this codes to Call Add_New_Dish

```
 public void addDishButton_Onclick(String categoryName)
    {
        Intent addDishIntent = new Intent(context, AddDish.class);
       addDishIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        addDishIntent.putExtra("categoryName", categoryName);
        context.startActivity(addDishIntent);

    }
```

and this codes to return to Menu, where the errors display:

```
public void homeButton_OnClick()
    {

        System.exit(2);
        finishActivity(1);
       // finish();
    }
```

Comment: System.exit seems wrong in an Android app

Comment: And related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117690/whats-the-difference-between-finish-and-finishactivityint-requestcode-in-and

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: Phan Văn Linh: Error Message: Unfortunately, name_of_apps has stoped. Then, the Main Activity is displayed

Comment: #Cricket_007: but why I can use it in Menu activity to return to Main activity

Comment: why not just call `onBackPressed()` ?

Comment: Thanks guy, I got the answer here. It's simple, put the finish() before the System.exit(). That's it:

 public void homeButton_OnClick()
    {
        finish();
        System.exit(1);
    }

Comment: I got my solution, but honestly, I don't understand what's the differentce